# Convert variable into function

Tags: function-construction, syntax, inputfield

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I have a variable called `H`.  `H` is some complicated function of `s`.

Now I want to make this variable `H` into a formal function `f[s]`. I've tried just doing

```
f[s_] := H
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

`H` was initially a value in a `InputField` and the type on that `InputField` was an `Expression`.

Any ideas on how I can turn this into a proper *Mathematica* function?

Comment: `h = 3*s - 1; f[s_] := Evaluate@h;` then `f[3]`

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ways, e.g.:

```
ClearAll[h, f]

h = 2 s + 3 s^2 + Sin[s];
f[sarg_] := h /. (s -> sarg)
f[2]

(* just define directly *)
ClearAll[h, f]
f[s_] := 2 s + 3 s^2 + Sin[s]
f[2]

(* 
16 + Sin[2]
16 + Sin[2]
*)
```